# Google Android RadioButton

Tags: android

У меня возникла проблема:

Есть три радио-кнопки.

Как сделать так, чтобы, когда размеры экрана не могут вместить все три кнопки,  размещенные горизонтально, последняя кнопка размещалась в другой ряд.

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях принято использовать т.н. `FlowLayout`. Единственная проблема в том, что его нет в комплекте поставки Android SDK, зато есть масса сторонних реализаций разной степени глубины проработки. Я например использую [эту реализацию](http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/) - просто и незатейливо. Зато работает.

Comment: Но ведь контейнер для радио кнопок, это радио группа

Comment: Тогда придется или без `RadioGroup` и вручную отрабатывать логику переключения кнопок `RadioButton` или переписывать `FlowLayout` чтобы он реализовывал логику `RadioGroup`

Comment: это слишком сложно проще  сделать сразу три кнопки в два ряда, расположены треугольником